# how to replace an id value to another value and as well as javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two problems

1) First Problem

I want to replace the current id value with a new value. So technically whenever someone click on the `a` tag, event will fire up which will be in the jquery code. I want to change the id value. For example

Whenever someone clicks a button

```
<div class="video" id="wistia_1223"></div>
```

**to**

```
<div class="video" id="wistia_4455"></div>
```

2) Second Problem

How do i change the value in the script tag via jquery? For example I want to change

```
<script>
       wistiaEmbed = Wistia.embed("wistia_1223", {
                playerColor: "ff0000",
                videoQuality: "hd-only",
                videoFoam: true
            });
    </script>
```

**to**

```
  <script>
       wistiaEmbed = Wistia.embed("wistia_4455", {
                playerColor: "ff0000",
                videoQuality: "hd-only",
                videoFoam: true
            });
    </script>
```

Full code

```
<div class="video" id="wistia_1223"></div>
<a class="videoClick">Click me</a>
<script>
   wistiaEmbed = Wistia.embed("How to change in here as well?", {
            playerColor: "ff0000",
            videoQuality: "hd-only",
            videoFoam: true
        });
</script>
```

Jquery code

```
$(function() {

  $(".videoClick").click(function(e){

    var wistia = "wistia_4455";
    $('.wistiaVideo').attr('id',wistia);
    wistiaEmbed = Wistia.embed(wistia, {
        playerColor: "ff0000",
        videoQuality: "hd-only",
        videoFoam: true
    });

  });



});
```

I tried the jquery code but it fails. It doesnt change the `id` and `script tag value`

Comment: Changing `id` values is not a great idea - they are meant to be static. Why do you want to do this? This question seems like an X-Y problem. If you could explain a little about what you're trying to achieve I'm sure there is a better way of doing it

Comment: wistia video website has a unique id and i need to change it to change to a new video.

Comment: Basically it is a playlist and whenever someone clicks on one of the videos then it will automatically changes the video.

Comment: You should use data attribute to keep video id dynamic, changing Id attribute is not a good practice

Comment: where in your code is "courseId" id? could you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: I just updated the question, to improve clarity.

Answer (score 0):

For First problem:

Find the element by using class selecter and change attribute value of id to you want like

```js
$('.video').attr('id',yournewid);
```

```html
<div class="video" id="wistia_1223"></div>
```

For second problem define variable and pass the variable to your function instead passing direct value.

so when you change value of variable with your new value then your code start operating on new value automatically

```js
<script>  
var myValue = "wistia_1223';

wistiaEmbed = Wistia.embed(myValue, {
  
  
  // you can change value of variable myValue as per your requirement
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your approach and let Wistia APIs do the job via Javascript.
The API offers a replaceWith() method which allows you to change the content of the current video with another video:

```
$("#video_abcde12345").click(function() {
    video.replaceWith("abcde12345");
});
```

See: https://wistia.com/doc/player-api#replacewithhashedid_options